# Замена символа в выведенной строке в консоли на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли способ или библиотека на python с помощью которой мы можем заменять символы в уже выведенном тексте в консольной программе.

Например: нам вывело три звездочки: ***, после прохода n-го времени или цикла или т.п. они заменяются на x-ы: xxx.

Если существует способ это сделать дайте ссылку на библиотеку и код решения (Если можете).

Comment: Работа с консолью существенно зависит от ОС. Этот момент следует уточнить. А так да, существует.

Comment: В командной строке windows 10 64bit

Comment: Вот пример упоавления курсором. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Python  Самое главное не понятно зачем это все? Сотрите экран и снова напишите. Задача у вас какая?

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли нужно что бы python с помощью print вывел символы на экран консольной программы, через 5 секунд нужно чтобы язык заменил эти символы на другие и так много раз, Я хочу тем самым сделать такую анимацию.

Comment: Я вас понял. Привел пример перемещения курсора в позицию экрана. 1. Перемещаете курсор. 2. Выводите новый текст. И так сколько хотите раз. Но лучше не использовать для этого консоль в Питоне. Вы же понимаете, что вывод идет в текущей позиции курсора?

Comment: @becouse Проверьте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#Python вот более правильный вариант ссылки.

Comment: Что конкретно вы не совсем поняли?

Comment: Все понял но это не совсем подходящий ответ смысл в том что это должна делать программа автоматически а не я заменять символы

Comment: Что то странное. Как программа будет что-то делать если вы не написали код? Я привел ссылку. Там пример перемещения курсора. Пример написан на Питоне. Это язык программирования. Вы в свою программу вставьте этот пример.

Comment: Ааа. Вы подумали, что 1. Перемещаете курсор 2. Выводите текст это для вас как человека? Отнюдь нет. Это вы как программист пишите программу с такими действиями.

Comment: Все я понял сейчас не могу протестировать, как появится время сделаю вердикт

Comment: Спасибо за помощь))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

def getPlus ():
    print('+++', end='')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print('\r', end='')

def getMinus ():
    print('---', end='')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print('\r', end='')

while True:
    getMinus()
    getPlus()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Возможно поздно, но это работает. Принцип работы понятен, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ctypes import windll
from time import sleep
# следующие 2 строки нужны чтобы нормально работал переход в начало консоли
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
print("\x1b[H" + '\n'*100) # стоит очистить консоль иначе старый текст останется
for i in range(10):
    sleep(1)
    print("\x1b[H") # переход в начало консоли
    print(i) # нужное значение
    print("any text after\nother text after") # любой текст
```